# For loop variable always evaluating to true

Tags: objective-c, ios

Annoying newbie problem here.  This variable `isPlayerTouchingAnotherPlayer` is being set to true as soon as I touch the piece.  I'm almost positive I know why but I can't find a way to display this in log to confirm.  I could probably do it by setting different flag numbers for each of the objects but I was hoping there is another way.

The problem is that `piece` is an object that is also located in `p1Array` so as soon as I touch it it hits itself and `isPlayerTouchingAnotherPlayer` is evaluated to true.

Is there a way I could print out the view or image name of the objects touching somehow to confirm this?  And furthermore, is there a way to somehow avoid this annoying conflict.

```
for (int i = 0; i <[p1Array count]; i++) {
    UIImageView *tempP1;
    tempP1 =[p1Array objectAtIndex:i];

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(piece.frame, tempP1.frame)) {
        NSLog(@"selected piece: %@, touched piece: %@ ", piece, tempP1);
        isPlayerTouchingAnotherPlayer = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use fast enumeration and skip the image view you are not interested in checking.

```
for (UIImageView *imageView in p1Array) {
    if (imageView == piece)
        continue;

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame, piece.frame)) {
       // do whatever
    }
}
```

it seems like you are already printing out the names of the objects touching in the code sample you have provided. if you want to print out specific properties of the objects you can do that to.

Comment: That NSLog doesn't work though, not with %@ and object name. It gives me bunch of useless memory info :)

Answer (score 0):

> as soon as i touch it it hits itself and isPlayerTouchingAnotherPlayer
>   is evaluated to true.

Then you should get a log message that shows the same object for the selected piece and the touched piece. If that's what's happening, then just add a condition to your `if` to prevent it:

```
if (piece != tempP1 && CGRectIntersectsRect(piece.frame, tempP1.frame)) {
```

Comment: duhhh, can't believe i didn't remember that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@", piece, tempP1);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%ld %ld", (NSInteger) piece, (NSInteger) tempP1);
```

The first will show you the description of the object, the second the address in memory, if it's same address, it's the same object.

You can simply check if it's the same object (pointer) with a simple equal check to exclude the same object :

```
if (piece != tempP1) {
   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(piece.frame, tempP1.frame)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, you would like to write this:

```
for ( int i = 0; 
     (  ( i < [p1Array count] ) 
     && ( ! isPlayerTouchingAnotherPlayer )
     ); 
     i++
    ) {
 ...
}
```